# Linq-to-SQL 3 tables, get result as List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

Today i ask this question, but i missed something so ill describe more in this question.

I have three tables:

```
[Table1]
 - ID // Unique
 - Name
 - Location
 - Country

[Table2]
 - ID - Unique
 - Table1.ID
 - Value

[Table3]
 - Table2.Value
 - LN
 - Name
```

Relationships:

One Table1.ID to many Table2.Table1.ID

What i need is ling-to-sql query where ill get result like

1. Get all from Table1
2. For all Table1.ID in Table2.Table1.ID get Table2.Value as array (int)
3. For all Table2.value as array(int), get array string Table3.Name where Table2.Value equals Table3.Table2.Value and LN = "en"

Example:

Table1

```
 ID |  Name    |  Location    |   Country   |
  1 | TestName | TestLocation | SomeCountry |
```

Table2

```
 ID  |  FK | Val |
  1  |  1  |  5  | 
  2  |  1  |  7  |
```

Table3

```
Val | Ln |  Name     |
  5 | en | Testname1 |
  7 | en | Testname2 |
```

Result:

```
1,TestName,TestLocation,SomeCountry,List<string>{Testname1,Testname2}
```

My ling to sql query get only Table2.Value as List, maybe you can make some modification.

```
 var result = (from t1 in context.Table1

              select new CLASS
              {
                  ID = t1.ID,
                  NAME = t1.Name,
                  LOCATION = t1.loc,
                  COUNTRY = t1.Country,
                  CategoryArray = new List<int>(t1.Tabel2.Select(p => p.CategoryID).ToArray())

              }).Take(10).ToList();
```

ASP.NET C# 4.0 LINQ TO SQL

Comment: Asking for a List is almost always **wrong**. Try to think in terms of an IEnumerable instead.

Comment: @frenchie it forces you to load all the results into RAM at once, which is often not desirable, it ties you to a specific collection type rather than creating code that can be easily used no matter what kind of sequence you want, and it means that any further composition of the results must first iterate over everything you have to this point without any chance for lazy enumeration.

Comment: What if you want to FORCE immediate execution? He wants a list of type CLASS (not the best name btw) and he gets such list right away.

Answer (score 2):

You need a sub-query; try this:

```
{
    ID = t1.ID,

    NAME = t1.Name,

    LOCATION = t1.loc,

    COUNTRY = t1.Country,

    CategoryArray = (from t3 in Table3
                     where t2.Value == t3.Value && t3.Ln == "en"
                     select t3.Name).ToList()
}
```

If in the CLASS object model you defined CategoryArray as `List<int>` then you need to use `.ToList()` instead of `.ToArray()`

I didn't find this very clear: *"For all Table2.value as array(int), get array string Table3.Name where Table2.Value equals Table3.Table2.Value and LN = "en"* Not sure if you also needed a join with Table1 for the sub-query.

Comment: Check Joanna answer, that`s the right query, but also check my comment there to see what i want as result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a multi-join would work in this example ?

I thought about something along these lines:

```
 var result =   from a in table1
                join b in table2 on a.id equals b.table1id
                join c in table3 on b.value equals c.table2value
                select new {Value = b.value, Name = c.Name}
```

I'm not sure what you'd like to group the results by - but if the above works, then you can group by either value or id probably to get the list of names. 
Without the data it's not easy to test this though.

**EDIT:**

If you're happy with the query in your post, then to get a list of all names associated with all values in the CategoryArray you can try this query:

```
var res = table3
            .Where(c => CategoryArray.Contains(c.table2value))
            .Select(c => c.Name)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: That`s the exactly as mine query but since [a] can have many [b] i receive result like

id=1 , name=test , value = test1
id=1 , name=test , value = test2
id=1 , name=test , value = test3

but i need something like this

id=1, name=test, value = test1,test2,test3

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - does it mean that all the items that have table1id the same will have the same name ? Otherwise can you explain how would you select the name from your comment above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can with this also :

```
public List<string> GetClientImagePath()
        {
            //return objDAL.GetClientImagePath();
            List<string> clientimagepath = new List<string>();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                ds = objDAL.GetClientImagePath();
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "clientimagepath";
                    clientimagepath = (from DataRow dr in ds.Tables["clientimagepath"].Rows
                                       select Convert.ToString(dr["ImagePath"])
                                        ).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return clientimagepath;
        }
```